# Substring replacement in Java

Tags: java, substring

I am trying to implement substring replacement, but I am not getting the desired results. Can someone comment on what I may missing here?

```
public class SubtringReplacement {

    public static void main (String[] args){

        String input = "xPIy";
        if (input.contains("PI") || input.contains("pi") || input.contains("Pi")){
            input.replace("PI", "3.14");
        }
        System.out.println(input);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are immutable!!

```
input = input.replace("PI", "3.14");
```

Comment: and change it to one condition `input.toLowerCase().contains("pi")`

Comment: @YogendraSingh _Strings are immutable!!_

Comment: @JigarJoshi - The original condition does not match "pI", so the simplification is not equivalent.

Comment: @Ted yes but looking at the purpose of replacement it seems like it is missed

Comment: @JigarJoshi - I agree, but it's worth pointing out the difference, in case it was a deliberate omission.

Comment: Thank you. I knew that, but now I have experienced it :). @Jigar: Thanks, I was also looking to combine those into one boolean.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you need to capture the return value when you do the replacement. The other problem is that you will only replace upper case `"PI"`, while it seems you want to replace mixed case instances. Try this instead:

```
input = input.replaceAll("(PI|pi|Pi)", "3.14");
```

`replace` looks for a literal match; `replaceAll` does a regular expression match, which is what you need.

By the way, you don't need the `if` condition -- if there is no match, there will be no replacement.

P.S. Look at the comment by @NullUserException if you also want to replace instances of `"pI"`.

Comment: @NullUserException - Yeah, except I just noticed that OP excludes "pI", so I updated the r.e.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying .matches() to work with regular expressions, but this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you were missing the Left hand assignment to make your code working with given conditions.

```
    input.replace("PI", "3.14");
```

But it will only replace, if `input` contains `PI` while it will attempt for `pi` and `Pi` as well. To better handle this, I think you can use `"[pP][iI]"` or `"[pP]{1}[iI]{1}"` as replacement pattern, which will look for one occurrence of `P or p` followed by one occurrence of `I or i` e.g. below:

```
   String input = "xPIyPizpIapib";
   input = input.replaceAll("[pP][iI]", "3.14"); 
   System.out.println(input); //<- all "pi"s irrespective of case are replaced.

   String input = "xPIyPizpIapib";
   input = input.replaceAll("[pP]{1}[iI]{1}", "3.14"); 
   System.out.println(input); //<- all "pi"s irrespective of case are replaced.
```

Please Note: This will also replace `pI` as wel, if found.

Comment: You don't need the count; `"[pP][iI]"` works equally well. Also, OP's original code excluded `"pI"`.

Comment: @TedHopp: Thanks! I added both in the answer as notes.